# Sizing relative to the parent working diffeently on firefox and chrome

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using .h-75 from Bootstrap to resize an image relative to its parent div. On Firefox resizing works, but on Chrome it seems to ignore it.

I tried adding object-fit:cover but it didn't work.

```html
  <div class="container d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
    <div>
      Some objects
    </div>
    <div class="mb-3" style="max-height: 50vh;">
      <img src="./img/mmm.png" class="d-none d-sm-inline h-75">
      <p class="mt-1 lead">some text</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      Some objects
    </div>
  </div>
```

I'd like chrome to dynamically resize the image when I reduce the viewport the same way firefox does it.

Comment: picture resizing is always a little funky... I would recommend styling the image to be a display: block element so it acts a little more like a div :)

Comment: changing inline to block pushes the image to the left of the screen and can't get it to align back to center

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I got the intended behavior by chnaging from mex-heigh vh, to just vh.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Solution: ->
    Insted of using h-75 class, you can try img-fluid class to <img> tag...it adjust automatically according to viewport.

    <div class="container d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
        <div>
          Some objects
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3" style="max-height: 50vh;">
          <img src="./img/mmm.png" class="d-none d-sm-inline img-fluid">
          <p class="mt-1 lead">some text</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          Some objects
        </div>
      </div>

You can try this...
```

Comment: If you are using bootstrap 3 version than you can use the "img-responsive" class.

Comment: tried it, now the image doesn't work properly on both browsers

Answer (score 0):

```
Solution: ->        
If you adding max-height on parent div 50vh... So you have to add height same as max-height..

        Here is the code...

        <div class="container d-flex flex-column min-vh-100">
            <div>
              Some objects
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3" style="max-height: 50vh; height: 50vh">
              <img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AGF-l7-BBIcC888A2qYc3rB44rST01IEYDG3uzbU_A=s900-mo-c-c0xffffffff-rj-k-no" class="d-none d-sm-inline h-75 img-responsive">
              <p class="mt-1 lead">some text</p>
            </div>
            <div>
              Some objects
            </div>
          </div>

    I tried on both browsers Firefox and chrome...
```